# python for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, signature

so evidently you write for loops in python int he following:

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    print i
```

but what if I'm actually using i as a counting trick and I specifically wanna do something like:

```
for (int i = 100; i > 20; i--)
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20 ; i += 2)
```

do you seriously have to write this in the body of the loop rather than the signature....

Comment: If you're using Python 2, use `xrange` instead of `range` in for loops (and anywhere else you don't actually need the whole range as a list).

Comment: While both of your examples can be trivially done with `range()`, in practice you will find that you should very rarely use it when you write `for` loops in Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Different languages use different semantics to say the same thing.  You can use the range function in several ways and it has as its arguments:

```
range(start, stop, jump)
```

So I can do

```
range(10, 1, -2)
```

to get a list like:

```
[10, 8, 6, 4, 2]
```

Using the three arguments of range you can get back to your counting tricks from C#, C++, C or Java.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
for i in range(100,20,-1): 
    print i
```

and

```
for i in range(0, 20, 2): 
    print i
```

Answer (score 1):

You do something like this:

```
for i in range(100,20,-1):
   print i
```

or

```
for i in range(0,20,2):
   print i
```